# How to implement various behaviour in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

I have a site to which the administration uploads the code written with PHP which is saved in the database. The uploaded code must be launched on the site when opening a special page.

Maybe there are some ideas how this can be implemented without `eval()`?

Comment: No, eval is the way. Not sure about efficiency but what it mostly is is very insecure... I think a better idea might be to review the way your admin is deploying new code. How did this situation come about? What kinds of jobs do these scripts do?

Comment: @ADyson In fact, the administrator of this site is only myself :) My site is a site for teaching mathematics using interactive trainers. Each trainer looks different and should work differently. For each trainer, I upload the code for sending the task to the user and the code for checking the answer from the user

Comment: If you're the admin then why not deploy this code as proper PHP scripts? No doubt you can sftp it to the server. Then the config in your database can just be the names of the script files to execute.

Comment: Oh, it looks like this is a good idea :D Thanks, I'll try to implement it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval()` can be used in such way if there are no security issues. But also creating PHP class files and making object instances of it dynamically via `new $classNameString` was a solution for me.